# Joomla 3.x Access Control / user role

Tags: joomla-3.x, mysql, fabrik

I'm using Fabrik 3.2 Form builder to build a shipment tracking system (like DHL) using Joomla 3.x. I have built the form & added some records. Now what I want is when a customer logs in using the Joomla Login Form, I want them to access their record(s) only to check their tracking.

Like Select all elements( username,email, status, etc) from table name (Tracking) where username(from the Tracking table)=logged in username.

How can I do that?

Comment: From the Close Vote reason: "Generally questions that ask for coding a solution must present some effort and that the user is in place to understand what the code is about."

Answer (score 1):

Check the prefilters of fabrik
http://fabrikar.com/forums/index.php?wiki/pre-filters/

Comment: Asking someone to "check a forum hyperlink" is not much of an answer -- it would be better positioned as a comment.  If there is a particular piece of information on that page that will resolve this issue, you should write the content directly into your answer.   I have already flagging this post as Not An Answer, but the Moderators declined my flag.